# jQuery UI DatePicker No Weekends with Min Date Shows Wrong Date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Strange one, I'm trying to specify a min date with no weekends - trouble is when I specify the min date as 2012, 10, 29 - the picker seems to default to November and doesn't let me scroll back to october! Ive created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sN63A/ to demonstrate the problem!

If I specify "9" instead of "10" for the month attribute it does show october but this makes me a little uneasy as I'd like to know at least why it doesn't work as expected!

I'm simply doing this for the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sN63A/  :

```
<input id="pickDate" type="text" />​

$('#pickDate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
    minDate: new Date(2012, 10, 29, 0, 0, 0, 1)
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Months starts with Jan = 0;Feb =1;mar=2.So if `2012, 10, 29` is given, it would default to November which is normal behavior.
Min Date in this case would mean that you are not allowed to go back before October.

```
    $('#pickDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        minDate: new Date(2012, 10 - 1, 25) 
   });
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sN63A/1/)

Comment: As I said in the question this will work but I wouldn't consider it to be "working properly". Thanks for the effort anyway but its not really the answer I was looking for as id already tried this.

Comment: YES! Thank you I was indeed being quite stupid and remember vaguely about months being weird in JS - I take back my previous remark many thanks! ;o)